# When to use "avoir X en tête" vs "avoir X dans la tête" vs "avoir X derrière la tête"

Tags: allemand, connotation, nuance

We were having a conversation in German, and I said:

> Er mag zwar ein richtiger kleiner Unruhestifter gewesen sein und hatte vielleicht immer nur Unfug im Kopf, aber wenn er **sich** etwas **in den Kopf gesetzt** hatte, dann wollte er es auch unbedingt bis zum Ende durchziehen.

I was wondering how I'd express the same idea in French, and I'd have said:

> ≈ Il était peut-être chahuteur, toujours partant pour faire des bêtises, mais quand il **avait** une idée **en tête**, il allait jusqu’au bout.

---

The expression "***sich etw. in den Kopf setzen***" -- literally translating as "***se mettre en tête***" -- tends to have a positive connotation in German, often coupled with something positive like "*un but*".

In French, the literally translated "*se mettre en tête*" does not work here due to its pejorative connotation, for one thing, leaving aside the structural difference: "*Quand il se mettait en tête **de** faire qch., ...*". Then, three other expressions with the noun "tête" come to mind:

1. "***avoir qch. en tête***": the one I used, and the phrase seems to take on a positive or negative meaning, depending on the noun used.
2. "***avoir qch. dans la tête***": I get the impression that this one carries a pejorative connotation, as I tend to use it in something like: "*Quand il avait une idée dans la tête, il ne l'avait pas ailleurs*".
3. "***avoir qch. derrière la tête***": I think this one is on the positive side, and with a hint of secrecy, as in "*have sth. up your sleeve*".

Answer (score 5):

**Avoir une idée en tête** c'est penser à quelque chose ou avoir l'intention de faire quelque chose.

- J'ai en tête de lire le dernier livre de Haruki Murakami. (→j'ai l'intention de lire le dernier livre de Haruki Murakami.

**Avoir dans la tête** peut avoir le même sens, mais ça apporte souvent une connotation supplémentaire :

- J'ai cet air dans la tête. (persistance, il ne me quitte pas)
- Mais qu'est-ce que t'as donc dans la tête ? (remarque négative, reproche)

Dans le contexte de la situation de la question je dirais plutôt

> quand il avait une idée dans la tête il allait jusqu'au bout.

parce que que ça rend mieux l'ancrage dans la tête, la volonté de la personne de faire ce qu'elle a en tête. Mais je reconnais que la différence est ténue et je ne suis pas sûre que tout le monde sente cette différence :  « en tête » restant au niveau de l'idée et « dans la tête » reflétant une volonté d'exécuter.

Il y a l'expression « **en avoir dans la tête** » qui signifie être intelligent. C'est plutôt familier.

**Attention aux différences de sens aux formes négatives** :

- Il n'a rien dans la tête  (→Il est bête).
- Il n'a rien en tête (→ Il n'a aucune idée sur la question, il n'a pas d'intention particulière).

**Avoir quelque chose derrière la tête** a un sens un peu différent. Ça dénote qu'on a une idée qu'on garde cachée pour l'instant mais avec l'intention de faire quelque chose (ça peut être un mauvais coup, ce n'est pas forcément positif), éventuellement par surprise.

Comment: I see. To wrap things up, which one of these phrases would you go for in this context?

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens Edited my answer.